# Azure DevOps Pipeline: same template twice in one stage

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

In my main pipeline in one stage, I call the same (deployment) template twice with just a bit different data:

```yaml
//pipeline.yml

- stage: dev
   condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'dev'))
   variables: 
      getCommitDate: $[ stageDependencies.prepare_date.set_date.outputs['setCommitDate.rollbackDate'] ]
   jobs:        
     - template: mssql/jobs/liquibase.yml@templates
       parameters:
         command: update
         username: $(username_dev)
         password: $(password_dev)
         environment: exampleEnv
         databaseName: exampleDB
         databaseIP: 123456789
         context: dev
         checkoutStep:
           bash: git checkout ${{parameters.commitHash}} -- ./src/main/resources/objects
  
     - template: mssql/jobs/liquibase.yml@templates
       parameters:
         command: rollbackToDate $(getCommitDate)
         username: $(username_dev)
         password: $(password_dev)
         environment: exampleEnv
         databaseName: exampleDB
         databaseIP: 123456789
         context: dev
```

```yaml
//template.yml

parameters:
- name: command
  type: string
- name: environment
  type: string
- name: username
  type: string
- name: password
  type: string
- name: databaseName
  type: string
- name: databaseIP
  type: string
- name: context
  type: string
- name: checkoutStep
  type: step
  default: 
    checkout: self

jobs:
- deployment: !MY PROBLEM!
  pool: 
    name: exampleName
    demands:
    - agent.name -equals example
  environment: ${{ parameters.environment }}
  container: exampleContainer
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
          ...
```

My problem is that the deployment cannot have the same name twice.
It is not possible to use the `${{parameters.command}}` to distinguish between deployments names, because it contains forbidden characters. Only `${{parameters.command}}` differs between two calls.

My question is whether it is possible to distinguish the name of a deployment other way than passing another parameter (e.g. jobName: ). I have tried various conditions and predefined variables but without success.

Additionally, I should add DependsOn so that the second template is called for sure after the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible because `getCommitDate` and thus command parameter in your second stage contains runtime expression and job name needs compile time expression. So if you use `command` as job name at compile you have there `rollbackToDate $(getCommitDate)`.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue, the job identifier should be empty in a template:

```
- job: # Empty identifier
```

More informations available [HERE](https://dexterposh.github.io/posts/004-azdo-tip-job/)